# How to access images from one meteor app to another meteor app

Tags: html, git, meteor

I have two separate meteor app(theme & admin) and also two separate repository on git for the same running on two different port(i.e theme run on localhost:3000 & admin run on localhost:3002). I want to access images of admin's public folder, in theme app on my local machine. How to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, You can directly access / include them via URL, like :

```
<img src="http://localhost:3002/PATH_TO_IMAGES/IMAGE.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an absolute URL, you can also record image URLs in a Mongo collection in your admin app.
In your theme app you can connect to your admin app database using [DDP.connect()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#DDP-connect) to get access to your other app's database.